# MySQL not rolling back the complete transaction (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have the following transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (1, 1, 0, 1);

    INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (1, 1, 0, 1);

COMMIT;
```

second query is giving primary key violation error but the transaction does not reach the `COMMIT;` statement and it is not rolling back the first `insert` statement. I want to roll back both records if there is an error in this transaction without using `stored procedures`